# Remove Git branch with case conflict

Tags: git

I accidentally made a branch with the same name as an existing branch, but different case:

```
$ git branch
* master
  issue_fix
$ git branch issue_Fix
```

I try to use `git branch` to list the branches, but get this error:

```
fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/heads/issue_fix (Case Conflict)'
```

I think git is trying to create the branch after converting to lowercase but this is a conflict. Checking the branch refs:

```
$ ls .git/refs/heads/
master
issue_fix
issue_fix (Case Conflict)
```

And in the ref logs

```
$ ls .git/logs/refs/heads/
master
issue_fix
issue_fix (Case Conflict)
```

I cannot delete with `git branch -D`

```
$ git branch -D "issue_fix (Case Conflict)"
error: branch 'issue_fix (Case Conflict)' not found.
```

Is it safe to just delete `".git/logs/refs/heads/issue_fix (Case Conflict)"` and `".git/refs/heads/issue_fix (Case Conflict)"`?

Comment: Which git version are you using?

Comment: git version 1.9.1

Comment: Testing in a sandbox, I can create branches with the same name but different case. I can't reproduce the problem in my question, though.

Comment: I am using v2.10. Let me check it with your version.

Comment: Can you rename it?

Comment: Oops, I have this whole repo in a Dropbox folder. "Case Conflict" is Dropbox's thing, not git's.

Answer (score 5):

I had my repo in a Dropbox folder, which is generally a bad idea. `(Case Conflict)` is Dropbox's marker for two files with the same lowercase name.

When I created a branch with one letter capitalized, Dropbox renames it to lowercase and adds the conflict marker.

I solved this by deleting the references to the branch, but I should also avoid keeping my repo in a Dropbox folder. It can do worse things than this.

Deleting with `git branch -D` doesn't work because the file name has the wrong format.

I deleted the files by hand:

```
$ rm ".git/logs/refs/heads/issue_fix (Case Conflict)"
$ rm ".git/refs/heads/issue_fix (Case Conflict)"
```

but I'm not sure this is totally safe.